# Not able to RDP with any other users

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, remote-desktop

I have a strange problem in my Active Directory using Windows Server 2008 R1. Only one of my users is able to make use of remote desktop functionality from the 50 users I have in my domain. The rest of the users are all in the same remote desktop group and have the same settings applied. I really cannot tell any difference between the users.

When trying to RDP with another user I get the following error.

"The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login."

I'm convinced that this is an AD issue and not on the client end but I am drawing blanks when it comes to troubleshooting the issue.

**Update**

I can actually login with the individual user without even being in the "Remote Desktop Users" group. Now, I'm really confused.

Comment: Are you using Remote Desktop Session Host?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean but my current setup is as follows. I have a server with the AD and 1x physical client PC and another 1x Virtual client PC. I want to connect from the physical client PC to the remote virtual client PC. This is only possible using one of my 50 users in my domain for which it works flawlessly. The remaining 49 users cannot connect at all, and I get the error "The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login.". I am using the built in RDP tool in Windows 7 on the client side. Sorry if I did not answer your question.

Comment: Is this one user by any chance an Administrator / in Domain Administrators group? Is it always THIS user or the FIRST user?

Comment: The user that is able to login is only part of the following groups. "Domain Users" & "Remote Desktop Users". This is true for all of the 50 users but only the same specific user can access the remote PC. I have tried adding other users to the "Administrator" group with no effect. Only the same specific user is able to login every time, regardless of priority.

Comment: So this rules out that you aren't using [Remote Desktop for Administration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770759.aspx) but actually trying to set up an [RD Session Host server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742822.aspx).

Comment: I am directly conencting to the virtual PC from the phsyical client PC. So no RDP Session Host Server involved.

Comment: In System Properties --> Remote tab. Under Remote Desktop, is "Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication" checked??? If so, is the user remoting from a computer that is either an ancient version of Windows or not using Windows???